# behaviour duplicate and inverse rows in a tableView (javafx)

Tags: javafx, tableview, observer-pattern

I have simplified the code to the following in an update of tableview.

For some reasons I do not use the property of JavaFx as one would expect, perhaps this behaviour is linked to this. Coming from JTable and observer pattern I wanted to try how to implement this in javafx. However the data of my table are all fine but when I am trying to change the colour of the background some more rows appears outside the range of the table. I have checked the size of the Observable list and it is as expected.

I cannot really see or understand how the datas.set generates this behaviour, would it be something that I miss with my code or then an expected behaviour with Javafx tableview.

Basically the logic used is I receive an update from another class (which I simulate here with the Thread), then I will update the corresponding row of the observable list with the updated data.

Thanks.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = new Pane();
            root.getChildren().add(new TableModel().getTable());
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package application;

import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableModel{

    private TableView<TableData> table = new TableView<>();
    private ObservableList<TableData> datas;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TableModel() {
        datas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        final TableColumn<TableData, Integer> cId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        cId.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, Integer>, ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<Integer> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, Integer> param) {
                        return new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(param.getValue().getId());
                    }
                });

        cId.setCellFactory(e -> new TableCell<TableData, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                // Always invoke super constructor.
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(String.valueOf(item));
                    if (getIndex() == 0) {
                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                    }else {
                         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        table.getColumns().addAll(cId);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.setItems(datas);
        table.setPrefSize(150, 450);

            datas.add(0, new TableData(0));
            datas.add(1, new TableData(0));
            datas.add(2, new TableData(0));
            datas.add(3, new TableData(0));
            datas.add(4, new TableData(0));


        new Thread(()->{
            while(true) {
                Random rand = new Random(10);
                update(rand.nextInt());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start(); ;

    }



    public TableView<TableData> getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void update(int num) {
        TableData data = new TableData(num);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    datas.set(0, data);
                });
    }

    private class TableData {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty cId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public TableData(Integer conid) {
            this.cId.setValue(conid);
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return cId.get();
        }

    }
}
```

Output with `datas.set(0, data);`

[image: output bug]

Output without `datas.set(0, data);`

[image: output expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 issues with your code:

#### Issue 1

```
final TableColumn<TableData, Integer> cId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
cId.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, Integer>, ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Integer> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, Integer> param) {
                return new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(param.getValue().getId());
            }
        });
```

This prevents changes of the property from triggering updates automatically. E.g.

```
table.getItems().get(0).cId.set(5);
```

would not result in an update of the table. To fix this return the property itself, not a newly created property that is initialized with the property's value at the time of the `cellValueFactory`'s execution.

```
final TableColumn<TableData, Number> cId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
cId.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Number> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, Number> param) {
                return param.getValue().cId;
            }
        });
```

#### Issue 2

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
    // Always invoke super constructor.
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
    } else {
        setText(String.valueOf(item));
        if (getIndex() == 0) {
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        }else {
             this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is incorrect given the fact that cells may become empty after being filled with a value. You should make sure the "empty" look is restored in case the cell becomes empty. This requires you to clear the style property:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
    // Always invoke supertype's implementation
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
        setStyle(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.toString());
        if (getIndex() == 0) {
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        } else {
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Issues 3 & 4

```
new Thread(()->{
    while(true) {
        Random rand = new Random(10);
        update(rand.nextInt());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

This thread will remain alive even if the GUI is shut down preventing the program from terminating. You can easily fix this by using a daemon thread.

Futhermore `Random` initialized with a seed returns deterministic results. Since you reinitialize `Random` with the same seed in every iteration of the loop, the value `rand.nextInt()` returns is always the same. You need to move the initialisation of the `Random` outside of the loop.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    Random rand = new Random(10);
    while (true) {
        update(rand.nextInt());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```